# $a_n=\frac{n +\sqrt n}{2n + \log(n)}$ Find If the sequence converges and its limit.

Tags: calculus

I don't know which test I should take to check for convergence.

When i solved this 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n +\sqrt n}{2n + \log(n)}$$ 
i got the result equal to $1/2$ but i am not sure. Looking for clarification.

Comment: What variable tends to infinity?$x,n$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry Dr. there is no X. I miss-typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using L'Hôpital's rule:  $\dfrac {1+\dfrac 1{2\sqrt n}}{2+\dfrac 1n}\to\dfrac 12$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=({1+\frac {\sqrt n } n})/(2+\frac {\log\, n} n) \to \frac 1 2$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}}{2+\frac{\log(n)}{n}}$$